# Why is ruby crashing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to use "redmine_git_hosting"  from `git://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting.git`

When I try to access it I get an error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/git_adapter.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant GIT_BIN
```

I can access the Redmine site but then if I refresh I get:

```
/usr/share/redmine_dev/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/git_adapter.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant GIT_BIN
[ pid=31351 thr=3075225872 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:817 time=2012-02-15 15:41:08.102 ]: The backend application (process 3677) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.
[ pid=3677 thr=-609445668 file=utils.rb:176 time=2012-02-15 15:41:08.103 ]: *** Exception NameError in application (uninitialized constant Redmine::Scm::Adapters::CommandFailed) (process 3677, thread #<Thread:0xb75931b8>):
```

I get a 500 Internal error.

From `top` I can see that one Ruby process was killed.

My environment is:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- PostgreSQL 8.4
- Apache2.20
- Ruby 1.8.7
- Redmine 1.3.0
- Phusion version 3.0.11
- Rails (2.3.14)
- Rubygems 1.6.2

Comment: You haven't given us enough to work on; We need to see source code.

Comment: The warning may or may not be part of the issue - it's just a warning. The bigger problem seems to be indicated by the output: `*** Exception NameError in application (uninitialized constant Redmine::Scm::Adapters::CommandFailed) (process 3677, thread #<Thread:0xb75931b8>):`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the same bug as this one reported against the Chiliproject fork: https://www.chiliproject.org/issues/828

> Seems this only happens in development mode, after the first request (from the second request on), since rails unloads your modules so you don't have to restart your app every time you make a change.
>   In the application_controller, all scm repository classes get loaded again with require_dependency on every request. But the modules these scm depend on like for example git_adapter and abstract_adapter get loaded with the standard ruby require, so they don't get loaded again. 
>   Hence the uninitialized constant errors in development.

There the suggested solution was to

> ... remove the requires from within the modules and integrate them to the application_controller :

```
  require_dependency 'redmine/scm/adapters/abstract_adapter'
  Redmine::Scm::Base.all.each do |scm|
      require_dependency "repository/#{scm.underscore}" 
      require_dependency "redmine/scm/adapters/#{scm.underscore}_adapter" 
  end
```